# Equivalent circuit with voltage buffer

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, circuit-design, circuit-theory

let's consider this circuit:

[image]

Consider the node A: it is at GND (0 V) because of the voltage buffer at right.

So my question is: is it possible to remove it and to consider the following simplified circuit, or we can only put VA = 0 but solving the circuit without removing the buffer?

[image]

Does the current I affect the circuit?

Are R1 and R2 in parallel?

Comment: Yes, yes.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Opamp sinks/sources whatever current it has to , to force the node A at 0 V due to the negative feedback.

The virtual ground makes it look like R1 and R2 are in parallel.

Assuming the Opamp is ideal, the same current I will flow into the "ground connection" as when opamp was there.

Answer (score 0):

Current \$I\$ (the current into the op amp's output) does affect the circuit, but you will have exactly the same current going into the ground connection if you replace the op amp with a direct connection to ground. (I am assuming that the op amp is ideal and that the input bias currents are zero.)